# CSS transition not being applied to dropdown item in menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, css-transitions

I have a Bootstrap menu and I want to add animated lines on hover. The CSS works perfectly with simple menu but doesn't work properly with dropdown menu. I want that the transition should work with dropdown menu as well. Below is the CSS and dropdown menu code. Please guide me how to modify the code so that it works with dropdown as well.

```css
.navbar a {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar a:after {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="navbar-nav" style="line-height:4">
  <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link nav-links" href="#">Home </a> </li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link nav-links" href="#"> About </a></li>
  <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link nav-links" href="#">Home </a> </li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link nav-links" href="#"> About </a></li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link  dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">  Hover up  </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu fade-up drop">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Submenu item 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Submenu item 2 </a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Submenu item 3 </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Change .navbar to .navbar-nav in css and try

Comment: Change .navbar to .nav-item in css

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the CSS, you have no element with a class of `navbar`.

Change this to `navbar-nav`

```css
.navbar-nav a {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-nav a:after {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}

.navbar-nav a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="navbar-nav" style="line-height:1.2">
  <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link nav-links" href="#">Home </a> </li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link nav-links" href="#"> About </a></li>
  <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link nav-links" href="#">Home </a> </li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link nav-links" href="#"> About </a></li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link  dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">  Hover up  </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu fade-up drop">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Submenu item 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Submenu item 2 </a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Submenu item 3 </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```